# How to change background colour for ck editor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor5

I Have a dark background so I applied color for ClassicEditor, Here is screenshot.
[image]

Its working fine until I focus-out of the editor its turning white again, Here is a Screenshot after Focus-out of the editor.
[image]

Here is my Code:

```
    ClassicEditor
      .create($("#desc")[0], {
          language: $("html").attr("lang"),
          alignment: {
              options: ['left', 'right']
          },
          autoParagraph : false
      })
      .then(editor => {
          myEditor = editor;
          myEditor.model.document.on('change', (event) => {
              $("#desc").val(myEditor.getData());
          });
           
            $(".ck-content").css("background-color", "rgb(32,41,64)");
            $(".ck-content p").css("color", "white");
            $(".ck-toolbar").css("background-color", "rgb(32,41,64)");
            $(".ck-button__label, .ck-icon").css("color", "white");
            myEditor.editing.view.document.on('change:isFocused', ( evt, data, isFocused ) => {
              if (isFocused) // blur
                  {
                    $(".ck-content").css("background-color", "rgb(32,41,64)");
                  }else{
                    $(".ck-content p").css("cssText", "background-color: rgb(32,41,64) !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 3px 6px;");
                  


                    //this one not working
                    $(".ck-editor__editable").css("cssText", "background-color: rgb(32,41,64) !important; padding : 0px;");
                  }
              });
          console.log(myEditor);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
      });
```

Comment: Why do you have `var(rgb(32,41,64))`? You only have vars when you declare them (e.g. `--myVar: blue;`), and the value certainly is not a variable. Get rid of that.

Comment: I forgot to change it but even though i pass it as background-color: rgb(32,41,64); it does nothing